Can I pass an unquoted column name as a property in S7 class?
can I pass an unquoted column name as property argument in S7 new_class() function?
The below returns an error
library(S7)
library(tidyverse)

test <- new_class(
  'test'
  ,properties = list(
    data=class_data.frame
    ,column=class_any
    )
)

test(mtcars,cyl)


You need to create a constructor:
test <- new_class(
  'test',
  properties = list(
    data = class_data.frame,
    column = class_name
  ),
  constructor = function(data, column) {
    column <- substitute(column)
    new_object(S7_object(), data = data, column = column)
  }
)

test(mtcars,cyl)
#' <test>
#'  @ data  :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
#'  .. $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#'  .. $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#'  .. $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#'  .. $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#'  .. $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#'  .. $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#'  .. $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#'  .. $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#'  .. $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#'  .. $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#'  .. $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#'  @ column: symbol cyl


thanks, can additional argument be passed to constructor function that are not properties of the class?

also why doesn't setter work in this case? just use setter to pass the value and enquo and assign it back to itself?
